# Mat.at< >(y, x) for arbitrary image depths

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, matrix, opencv3.1

**Short version**

Which is the most efficient and elegant way to modify a pixel value of a `Mat` object with `.at<>` no matter what depth the data has? Or, is there another simple approach without `.at<>`?

**Long version**

When modifying single pixels of a mat object, one has to know the depth of the matrix data for following call:

```
 m.at<uchar>(1, 2) = 10; //set pixel (1, 2) of Mat m to 10.
```

This gives wrong results if the matrix isn't `8U` but e.g. `16U` or `32F`.

I'm thinking of some approach with `switch` and one case for every template to use:

```
Mat m = (Mat_<uchar>(3, 3) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
switch (m.depth()) //8U
{
    case 0:
        m.at<uchar>(1, 2) = 12;
        break;
    case 4:
        m.at<int>(1, 2) = 12;
        break;
    //...
}
```

Are there some other possibilities for the issue? I'm concerned regarding performance as regularly all pixels of the image are modified.

Comment: Why a template, `Mat` is no template?

Comment: This question has been asked several time, where people where using approaches like yours. **But**, why do you need this? You write your algorithm, and you know exactly the type of each matrix. You could use `Mat_<Tp>` to make things easier, like `Mat1b` for grayscale images, and so on... Bottom line, write better code where you know what types you're working with, and avoid this mess.

Comment: @DieterLücking `Mat` doesn't have a template, but `Mat_` does

Comment: @Miki: I want to write code which can be used for both 8-bit and 16-bit data, but maybe you are right that I should convert the images to ``CV_32F`` (or something else) before starting to work.

Comment: you've at least 4 possibilities: 1. write your function for multiple types (hard to maintain because changes have to be done in each function - more work for coder). 2. check the input image. If it is not thw right type: convert it (steals some processing time and memory and maybe precision). 3. tell the user that a special type is required. Throw an exception if he provides the wrong type (more control to user but less comfortable - more work for user). 4. write a getPixelValue function that internally checks type of Mat (will be very slow). Choose wisely :)